# Specify external javascript data array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this:

```
<!-- Javascript -->
<script>
$(function () {
    var availableTutorials = [

        "MacKenzie, Randy",
        "Paciorkowski, Lev",
        "Johnston, Daniel",
        "Lionti, Michael",
    ];
    $(".automplete-2").autocomplete({
        source: availableTutorials,
        autoFocus: true
    });
});
</script>
```

But I want to just specify the names in an external javascript data array; like src="players.js";

How can I do that without breaking the javascipt?

Comment: Instead of `source: availableTutorials,`, just provide the URL like this `source: url`

Comment: for me the meaning of `external javascript data array; like src="players.js";` is absolutely unclear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just add them into a separate external javascript file, and include that file before your current file( where you want to use those names )

e.g in your players.js file somewhere on your server you have this code

```
window.players = [
  "John", "Mike"
]
```

Then, you include the players list in your header to preload them for quick use.

```
<script src="players.js"></script>
```

then, somewhere else

```
<script>
$( ".automplete-2" ).autocomplete({
        source: window.players,
        autoFocus: true
    });
});
</script>
```

As noted in comments, you pollute global namespace by adding properties to window object. Its fine, but you should try to add all your site specific properties into one custom sub-property that is unlikely to overlap with some third party library.

for example:

```
SiteData.players = []; // your preloaded player list
SiteData.config = {
    apiUrl: 'some url',
    env: 'test'
}
SiteData.userPreferences = {
    playersPerPage: 10,
    colorScheme: 'dark'
    ...
}
```

And so on.
This way you only have 1 property on global namespace.

Comment: Note that this means you are running the risk of polluting the global namespace.